# Date - inline start and end date

Tags: 7, datetime

On node creation date field is huge when there is end date (required), so i would like to have it inline like on this image:

[image]

Comment: Notice that technically you aren't asking any question; you are simply stating facts. Also, this kind of question is off-topic for us.

Comment: Ok, i tought question was clear from what i have wrote. So the question is how to move date under "to" next to date "date". Any reason why would it be off-topic ? Would be good to know for the future.

Comment: Its more of CSS related issue than Drupal problem. Anyway, something like this in your stylesheet could be good start `.container-inline-date {display: inline-block; width: auto;}` (dont know if you have same classes as i have, you should check it)